# PHP: Fatal Error: Maximum function nesting

Tags: php, python

I'm getting the following error message:

> PHPFata1error:Maximumfunctionnesting1eve1of'100'reached,aborting

I'm using python and open a php-file like:

```
work = commands.getoutput("./scripts/php-file " + str(art) + " < " + str(sys.argv[1]+str(".temp")))
```

I know that my problem has to do with

> xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100

and that I should change the value. But: I'm working on a (work-)server and I can't change this value. Is there any way to bypass this problem?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is there a reason why your PHP script needs a recursion depth of more than 100?  If that isn't a bug you might need to re-write the code to remove the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust the ini in your PHP code with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```